# Mumford–Tate 1962 "Algebraic geometry seminar" citation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ho.history-overview

In FGA 3.V, there is a citation for

> Mumford D. and Tate J., Séminaire de géométrie algébrique, Harvard University, Spring term 1962 (à paraître).

This seems to be the same seminar mentioned by Grothendieck in a letter to M. Artin on the 23rd of February, 1963 (see footnote 2 of letter number 19, page 71, of [this digitisation](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/Letters/AGMumford.pdf)), which says that

> Lichtenbaum’s notes on the lectures by Grothendieck, Mumford and Tate have not been published.

**Did these notes ever appear? Is there a better way to cite this seminar?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I asked Steve Lichtenbaum, and he wrote "I started to write up the notes for the Grothendieck-Mumford seminar but then Grothendieck left and I never finished.  The notes do not exist.  They probably should not have been cited."

Comment: can't get a more authorative answer than that, thank you so much!